# How to increase size of the points in ggplot2, similar to cex in base plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dummy code:

```
dt<-data.frame(country=letters[1:20],val=rnorm(20),siz=rnorm(20))
qplot(x=country,y=val,data=dt,geom="point",size=siz)
```

Now I want to increase the relative size of the points, since the resulting smallest point is too small. Is this possible to do by changing one parameter, like `cex` in base plots?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want `scale_size()` and it's argument `range` (or `to` according to the ggplot website):

```
qplot(x=country,y=val,data=dt,geom="point", size=siz) + 
    scale_size(range = c(2, 10))
```

Fiddle with the `range` to get suitable minimum/maximum sizes.

Comment: For the version of ggplot2 I am using (0.8.9) the argument is `to`, instead of `range`. And there it is in plain sight in the help page. How did I miss it, I do not understand.

Comment: And you mentioned `to` in your post too. My head is not working properly today.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure my workstation is up-to-date **ggplot2**-wise.

Comment: (+1): Great answer. Using `scale_size_continuous(range = range(dt$siz))` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MYaseen208 do not do that. The performance on that for a dimension that has lots of distinct values could crash R.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. Change the scale's range:

```
p <- qplot(x=country,y=val,data=dt,geom="point",size=siz)
p + scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,8))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I upvoted both, but I could accept only one.

Comment: May I ask how to remove that legend on the right side?

Comment: (+1): Great answer. Using `scale_size_continuous(range = range(dt$siz))` would be more appropriate.

Comment: If you get error (like me): `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` you can use `scale_size_manual(values = seq(3,8,6))` instead of `scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,8))`