# How to reverse the size in geom_point()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot positive and negative values with their proportional size represented by points such that 0 are smallest in both cases and largest are their magnitude. i e i want negative point size such that 0 is smallest and -5 is largest meantime for positive value 0 is smallest and 5 is largest. something like this image

[image]

I know i can revers and do this if it would be only one variable like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789613/how-to-increase-size-of-the-points-in-ggplot2-similar-to-cex-in-base-plots).

But i have two sizes.

My sample data and code are below.

```
dput(ddf)
structure(list(tr = c(0.192833333333335, 0.800378947368421, 2.28270774476556, 
0.586631034482762, 0.217825000000001, -0.773253846153845, -0.459235294117648, 
-0.0706142857142855, -0.24942, 11.1025623422045, -0.871375, -0.929300000000012, 
-5.92639999999999, 3.87432045251869, -3.62026818181818, -2.49045555555556, 
-0.730590000000007, 3.03523157894737, 1.04723333333333, -0.120474999999999
), Itr = c(0.192833333333335, 0.800378947368421, 2.28270774476556, 
0.586631034482762, 0.217825000000001, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.1025623422045, 
NA, NA, NA, 3.87432045251869, NA, NA, NA, 3.03523157894737, 1.04723333333333, 
NA), Dtr = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.773253846153845, -0.459235294117648, 
-0.0706142857142855, -0.24942, NA, -0.871375, -0.929300000000012, 
-5.92639999999999, NA, -3.62026818181818, -2.49045555555556, 
-0.730590000000007, NA, NA, -0.120474999999999), td = c("Increasing", 
"Increasing", "Increasing", "Increasing", "Increasing", "Decreasing", 
"Decreasing", "Decreasing", "Decreasing", "Increasing", "Decreasing", 
"Decreasing", "Decreasing", "Increasing", "Decreasing", "Decreasing", 
"Decreasing", "Increasing", "Increasing", "Decreasing"), lat = c(-58.07, 
-57.9, -56.74, -55.22, -55.43, -54.12, -54.62, -54.63, -54.48, 
-54.25, -52.89, -54.05, -49.79, -49.82, -48.83, -48.73, -49.69, 
-49.29, -48.89, -49.37), lon = c(130.82, 131.15, 131.67, 129.14, 
127.71, 127.42, 126.9, 128.43, 128.33, 130.17, 125.77, 128.69, 
123.2, 123.15, 124.05, 123.67, 125.03, 124.91, 124.97, 124.98
)), .Names = c("tr", "Itr", "Dtr", "td", "lat", "lon"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
20L))
```

Code:

```
plt<-ggplot()+
    geom_point(data = ddf,aes(x = lon, y = lat,size =  Itr,shape=td),fill="Blue")+
    geom_point(data = ddf,aes(x = lon, y = lat,size = Dtr,shape=td),fill="Green", show.legend = FALSE)+          
    scale_size_continuous(name="IDt",range=c(2,12))+
    scale_shape_manual(name= "td",values=c(25,24),labels=c("Decreasing","Increasing"))
plt
```

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035359/diverging-size-scale-ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstand the question, but the example you gave was:

```
require(ggplot2)
plt<-ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = ddf,aes(x = lon, y = lat,size =  Itr,shape=td),fill="Blue")+
  geom_point(data = ddf,aes(x = lon, y = lat,size = Dtr,shape=td),fill="Green", show.legend = FALSE)+          
  scale_size_continuous(name="IDt",range=c(2,12))+
  scale_shape_manual(name= "td",values=c(25,24),labels=c("Decreasing","Increasing"))
plt
```

[image]

and to reverse the scale based on absolute value it's:

```
require(ggplot2)
plt<-ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = ddf,aes(x = lon, y = lat,size =  abs(Itr),shape=td),fill="Blue")+
  geom_point(data = ddf,aes(x = lon, y = lat,size = abs(Dtr),shape=td),fill="Green", show.legend = FALSE)+          
  scale_size_continuous(name="IDt",range=c(12,2))+
  scale_shape_manual(name= "td",values=c(25,24),labels=c("Decreasing","Increasing"))
plt
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with your answer is, now the largest positive value got smallest size. The question is how to make size proportional in a way that value nearest to 0 are smallest ( both in figure and legend) and larger with increasing or decreasing magnitude ( both in map and legend).

Comment: @Cirrus Oh, okay. Absolute value then. No problem. I am working right now but I will update this as soon as I get a break.

Comment: any suggestions regarding the legend in your solution ?

Comment: @Cirrus Thanks for reminding me. I just made an update, can you see if that's what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I thought the question was asking about establishing a diverging size scale, where the values closest to 0 are smallest and those furthest from 0 are largest.

In order to accomplish that you need to modify `ddf` to include two new columes (`all_trs` combines `Dtr` and `Itr` and `abs_trs` is just the abosolute value of `all_trs` which you will use for the diverging size scale):

```
library(dplyr) library(magrittr)
ddf %<>% mutate(all_trs = ifelse(td == "Increasing", Itr, Dtr), abs_trs =abs(all_trs))
```

You could obviously build these the base way `ddf$all_trs <- ifelse(...)` but piping `%>%` is so much easier and cooler ;)

Once that's built in you can go ahead and make your plot like this:

```
plt <- ggplot(data = ddf, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = td)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = td, size = abs_trs, fill = td), alpha = .5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(25, 24)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2,20)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","red")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(all_trs,1))) +
  guides(size = F)
plt
```

[image]

I included the `geom_text` overlay to help show that size is scaling properly. Hope that helps!

Comment: Nathan Day your answer is absolutely good however how you present the legend with divergence i e how to show the legend like in original question. In your code guides(size = F) removed, it will show and odd legend. I want to show the legend as in the image of the question.Thanks.

Comment: If you want to bin your data like the legend you cut out above you are welcome to. It shouldn't be hard to set the appropriate naming for 3 levels in a legend, Sorry my solution only works with a continuous scale. You can easily turn scales back on if you think your readers won't be able to understand that point size is relative to value size.